# Gradually increase/decrease animation speed? [Android]

Tags: android, animation

I was working on animated effect on android, I would like to know if there's any other way to gradually increase/decrease the animation speed?

Is it possible to specify like first 3 second rate of change was slow, and the rest goes fast?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [Interpolator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Interpolator.html). For your case I would recommend the [AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator.html)

```
Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.your_animation);
anim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
image.startAnimation(anim);
```

As for the interpolator, you can build your own!

```
public class MyInterpolator extends Interpolator {

    public MyInterpolator(int valueCount) {
        super(valueCount);
    }

    public float getInterpolation (float input) {
        return (float)(Math.cos((input + 1) * Math.PI) / 2.0f) + 0.5f;
    }
}
```

Using [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28cos%28%28x%2b1%29%2api%29%20%2b%201%29/2) you can play with the parameters.

Comment: Cool, but how about getting it to execute with AnimatorSet?

Comment: `AnimatorSet` has `setInterpolator()` as well.

Comment: @laalto yes I saw it now:) But as what I've read from the AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator(), we seems unable to configure the rate of speed ?

Comment: @Roylee You can write your own `Interpolator`s if none of the built-ins http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Interpolator.html suit your needs. Basically, the interpolator is just a function that maps a float between 0 and 1 to another float.

Comment: @laalto Alright nice! By the way It would be fantastic if you were able to show it as answer :) So that others in the future might benefit from it as well.

Comment: @Roylee Added a custom interpolator class. Go to Wolfram Alpha and play with the function.